# Set ForwardX11 with ansible ssh config

Tags: ssh, ansible, netapp

While connecting to a managed host(netapp device) using `command` module, I get the below error.

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [10.20.30.40]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: X11 forwarding request failed", "unreachable": true}
```

How to set `ssh` setting "ForwardX11 no" with ansible configuration / ansible-playbook command line option.

I don't want to change ssh settings in user directory.

Comment: While connecting manually the same error is occurring as warning but command prompt shows up after it. This is a netapp device.  ssh 'mydomain\username'@10.20.30.40
Password:
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

Last login time: 11/17/2020 12:05:42
BLRBABCD01::>

Answer (score 0):

Try passing ssh arguments in command line `ansible-playbook --ssh-common-args='-o ForwardX11=no' <rest_of_the_commands>`